# How can I save each array data to database? one data as one row

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I used Django Rest Framework
It's only store the last element of array not all 3 elements

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add(request):
    serializer = modelSerializer(data=request.data)
    arr = ['a','b','c']
    if serializerVariant.is_valid():
        obj = serializer.save()
        for foo in arr:
            obj.value = foo
            obj.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializerVariant.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: That is logical: you each time make changes to the *same* object, so you save the object three times, and thus the value is the last one of the `arr` at the end.

Comment: So, what is the solution? I want to put these at a time

Comment: What is `.value`? A single `CharField`? or an `ArrayField` that wraps over a `CharField`?

Comment: The value from the html form is A,B,C

Comment: The value from the html form is A,B,C
I make an array from that
arr = request.data['value'].split(",")

Comment: You could try setting `obj.pk = None` after `obj.save()` which would create new rows on subsequent iterations of the loop, although without seeing any model code it's difficult to know whether it would work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it work with little customization